# Stripe POST to flask through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use a function that sends an ajax request when a stripe form gets submitted. I've tried using `.submit()` and it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Here's what I'm trying:

HTML

```
<form action="/download_data" method="post" id="paymentForm">
                    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                        data-key="{{ stripe_key }}"
                        data-description="A Flask Charge"
                        data-amount="500"
                        data-locale="auto"> 
                    </script>
                </form>
```

JS

```
$("#paymentForm").submit(function(event) {
    window.alert("HELLO")
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this),
        url = $form.attr('action');

    var formdata = $form.serialize();
    console.log(formdata)

    //AJAX will go here if I can get the function working
 })
```

And I don't think that this function is even getting called at all so I sort of stopped adding to it until I figure this out somehow. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How are you submitting the form? Is there a button? Have you tried using onsubmit? Do you see the hello alert? Did you try removing the preventDefault? Have you tried returning true? The title says ajax but you are trying to submit. What is going on here?

Comment: Just tested all of those; still nothing. I'm dead confused myself. If this just ends up not working I'm probably going to have to switch to https://stripe.com/docs/checkout but I see literally no reason why it isn't working. The checkout.js script generates a Modal with a the payment Input Fields along with the Submit button. When that submit button is clicked the form data is sent as a POST request to the action url on the form (/download_data in this case). The AJAX call is what I'm going to do after I can at least understand why the function isn't being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the ["custom integration"](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) method so you can define a callback that's called when Checkout creates a token, and you can then submit the token in an AJAX request (or do anything else you want):

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_...',
  token: function(token) {
    // Grab the token from `token.id` and send it in an AJAX request
  }
});
```

Here's a basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/ym0k4t9f/

Comment: This is what I ended up doing yesterday, so I guess I might as well select this.